# Not able to attach Target id(launch configurtion) to the target group of network load balancer in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I am configuring a Terraform script for creating HA rabbitmq setup with auto scaling groups for all the instances. For creating auto scaling group I am creating launch configuration which will create auto scalable instance.

I want to use a network load balancer in front of this instance so I have to create target group and target group attachments. Here I have to provide target_id(launch configuration id) to attach it with target group. But when applying script it shows the following error:

```
Error registering targets with target group: ValidationError: Instance ID 'rabbit' is not valid status code: 400, request id: 1cad37a8-b1da-416a-bc11-f50ae6b83cd2
```

**Terraform script**

```
resource "aws_lb" "rabbit" {
  name = "${local.cluster_name}-lb"
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  internal = "false"
  subnets = aws_subnet.subnet.*.id
  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = "true"
  tags = {
    Name = "${local.cluster_name}-lb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
    load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.rabbit.arn
    protocol = "TCP"
    port = "80"

    default_action {
        type = "forward"
        target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.TCP80.arn
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "TCP80" {
  name = "${local.cluster_name}-TCP80"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  target_type = "instance"

  protocol = "TCP"
  port = "80"

  health_check {
    protocol = "TCP"
    port     = 80

    # NLBs required to use same healthy and unhealthy thresholds
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3

    # Interval between health checks required to be 10 or 30
    interval = 10
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "TCP80" {
  count = var.controller_count
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.TCP80.arn
  target_id        = aws_launch_configuration.rabbit.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "rabbit" {
  name = "rabbit"
  image_id    = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name    = "key_name"

  security_groups = [
      aws_security_group.rabbit-nodes.id,
  ]
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "rabbit-node" {
  #name = "${var.name}-${var.environment_tag}-"
  name ="rabbit"
  #count = var.instance_count
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.rabbit.name
  vpc_zone_identifier  = aws_subnet.subnet.*.id
  min_size             = var.min_size
  max_size             = var.max_size
  desired_capacity     = var.desired_size
  termination_policies = ["OldestLaunchConfiguration", "Default"]
  #load_balancers       = ["${aws_lb.rabbit}"]

  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 300

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` resource is for connecting existing EC2 instances, ECS tasks or Lambda functions to a load balancer target group:

> `target_id` (Required) The ID of the target. This is the Instance ID
>   for an instance, or the container ID for an ECS container. If the
>   target type is ip, specify an IP address. If the target type is
>   lambda, specify the arn of lambda.

If you want to have all your instances in an autoscaling group be automatically attached to a target group then you can specify this with the [`target_group_arns` parameter on the `aws_autoscaling_group` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#target_group_arns):

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "rabbit-node" {
  #name = "${var.name}-${var.environment_tag}-"
  name ="rabbit"
  #count = var.instance_count
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.rabbit.name
  vpc_zone_identifier  = aws_subnet.subnet.*.id
  min_size             = var.min_size
  max_size             = var.max_size
  desired_capacity     = var.desired_size
  termination_policies = ["OldestLaunchConfiguration", "Default"]

  target_group_arns    = [aws_lb_target_group.TCP80.arn]

  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 300

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: But can i provide reference of launch configuration in target_id??

Comment: The AWS API won't take it. It must be an IP address, instance ID, ECS task ID or Lambda function ARN as mentioned in the documentation quoted above.

Comment: If this answer solved your question then you should consider marking it as accepted as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. This allows people to see that there is a solution to the problem if they also have the same issue. It also rewards you with 2 reputation.